# SharePoint: Get SPListItem by Unique ID

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am attempting to get an SPListItem object from a unique ID (GUID). From looking at several sites (inc. http://sharepoint400.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-spsitedataquery-to-find-list.html and http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Retrieving-an-Item-from-the-RootWeb-and-Subwebs-using-its-UniqueId.aspx) I came up with the code below.

```
const string QueryFormat =
@"<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='UniqueId' />
        <Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>";

            SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
            query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";
            query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='0'/>";
            query.Query = string.Format(QueryFormat, itemUniqueId);
            query.RowLimit = 1;
            //query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='WebID' /><FieldRef Name='ListID' /><FieldRef Name='ID' />";

            var results = SPContext.Current.Web.GetSiteData(query);
```

However, no matter what... I always seem to get zero rows returned. I don't understand why, because I know the Guids I am using are correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered adding a recursive type to your query? Could you also show us how and where you're passing in the GUID and in what form?

Are you only concerned with list items and not lists, webs or sites? Do you know the target list or web of the item?

Are you restricted to using CAML? Are you aware of the `$listItem = $spList.GetItemByUniqueId($targetGuid)` method?

As you can see, there are many questions that require answers before anyone can provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is an invalid type for Unique Id, it should be Guid.
Update your query:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/>
        <Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The field Type and TypeAsString for UniqueId is indeed Lookup.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to remove all the spaces in QueryFormat string. Use something like this instead:

```
"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"UniqueId\" /><Value Type=\"Lookup\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where>"
```

SharePoint doesn't like these spaces.

I would also suggest to use one of the libraries to generate Caml queries like:
http://camldotnet.codeplex.com/ 
or
http://camlex.codeplex.com/